# "On the surf" or "in the surf"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

> Vocal groups include enormously popular bands like The Beach Boys and Jan and Dean whose harmonic voices told stories of days **on the surf** and nights full of parties and hot rods. ([source](https://www.thoughtco.com/history-of-surf-music-3154327))

Since "surf" means a mass of foam pushed up by waves, it makes sense that surfers ride **on** top of the surf. However, Google seems to suggest that "on" is not a commonly used preposition before "surf". Most, if not all, of the results are "in the surf," as in:

> Gathered here are images from the past several months of people (and animals) **in the surf**, including professional surfers, amateurs, spectators, and more. ([source](https://www.theatlantic.com/photo/2011/09/in-the-surf/100148/))
>
> beachgoers romping **in the swirling surf** (source: Merriam Webster)

Comment: But surfers ride the surf. So the author chose **on** there. It's fine. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22out+on+the+surf%22&oq=%22out+on+the+surf%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3816j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "surf" is the waves breaking on the beach

Swimmers go in the water, and play *in* the surf.

Surfers go on a board and ride *on* the surf, but often fall *in*.

So the difference is simply the difference of meaning between "in" and "on". Just as a pencil can in *on a desk* or *in a desk*.